# json object key is getting added even if array has the key

Tags: javascript, json

I am looping through an array and checking if a second array has a key by that name. If not then add this current name as a key to second array. I check with `hasOwnProperty` and also with `in` but in both cases the key is getting added in second array though a key by that name is already present.How can stop a key getting added if it is already present?

```
function(){
    var _arraySource = ['Tea', 'Coffe', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Tea'];
    var _jsonArray = [];

    for(var i = 0, j = _arraySource.length; i<j; i++){
        if(_jsonArray.hasOwnProperty(_arraySource[i])){
            //Do nothing
        }
        else{
          var _key =_arraySource[i];
          var myObj = {};

          myObj[_key] = "";
          _jsonArray.push(myObj);
        }
    }

    console.log(_jsonArray);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zergjnLu/5/)

Comment: _sigh_.   It sounds like you need a "map" (or object) rather than an "array", but without knowing how the data is supposed to be used we can't tell.   If this is the case then the previous question you asked about variable key names is probably moot.

Comment: i.e. it's likely that you're not using the right data structure in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**_jsonArray** is array of object. You must check each objects, if the property is already there.

Try this code.

```js
var _arraySource = ['Tea', 'Coffe', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Tea'];
var _jsonArray = [];
  for (var i = 0, j = _arraySource.length; i < j; i++) {
    var obj = $.map(_jsonArray, function (data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(_arraySource[i]))
        return data;
      });
     if (obj.length) {
        console.log(_arraySource[i]);
     }
     else {
       var _key = _arraySource[i];
       var myObj = {};
       myObj[_key] = "";
       _jsonArray.push(myObj);
     }
  }
console.log(_jsonArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks it worked,btw I am also using web worker so I replace $.map with Array.prototype,map.call